# Build Url using ServletUriComponentsBuilder without port number in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` in my service class to build some urls but the problem is that it includes port number also where the servlet container is running, this is a problem when I am deploying my app on production behind a proxy server which is supposed to run only on port 80

Code that I am using is:

```
String sUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/student/edit/" + st.getId()).build().toUriString();
```

While `c:url` that I am using in JSP is working perfectly fine, it do not include port number. Is there any way by which `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` also start detects whether it needs to include port number or not.

Means if the application start on port `8080` then it can include port number but when app is accessed from port `80` then do not include?

Whats happening: If my tomcat is running on port 8080 while I have proxy server in place which serves request on port 80, but urls built by `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` still appends port `8080` after host, I need it to be `80`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ServletUriComponentsBuilder#fromRequest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/ServletUriComponentsBuilder.java?source=c):

```
String scheme = request.getScheme();
int port = request.getServerPort();
String host = request.getServerName();

String header = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Host");

if (StringUtils.hasText(header)) {
    String[] hosts = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(header);
    String hostToUse = hosts[0];
    if (hostToUse.contains(":")) {
        String[] hostAndPort = StringUtils.split(hostToUse, ":");
        host = hostAndPort[0];
        port = Integer.parseInt(hostAndPort[1]);
    }
    else {
        host = hostToUse;
     }
}
....
```

Especially the line

```
String header = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Host");
```

will do the trick. All you have to do is set [X-Forwarded-Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers) in your proxy server and start using **ServletUriComponentsBuilder#fromRequest** instead of **ServletUriComponentsBuilder#fromCurrentContextPath**. Your url should contain your public proxy hostname and no port.

Comment: Problem is that I am accessing this method from a service class and it does not have `HttpServletRequest` object in that method. Only way I know is to get it from controller and pass it to service class? Is this a correct way?

Comment: This is correct. But I would not recommend to pass HttpServletRequest into service layer. You shouldn't tie your service layer to web layer. But this already creeped into your codebase as long as you are building links inside your service. Extract link building to your web layer and your service should just return a domain object (pojo). You'll be able to reuse your service in another context without any fuss (Unittest, SOAP Webservices, Messaging and many more)

Comment: Yes you are right, I should not tie service layer with web layer. I am new to MVC and there is just one problem for which I don't understand where to put that code. I need to build a Map of `<String, List>` which is to be returned as JSON (for AJAX). I don't know where to write this code. I would be glad if you could suggest me something. In this list only I am putting those URLs also

Comment: Try to answer it by yourself. You want to return JSON in response to an ajax call. JSON and Ajax are highly related to the web. Where do you should put your code (answer is obvious :-))?

Comment: Seems obvious but i am really not getting it. Putting it into JSP doesn't seems right as it is just a `Map`, one option is to put it straight into controller, is this correct? But this `Map` gets data from `DAO`, for that I need to create some more methods in service class. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Yes. You should call a service from within your controller. Your service gives you your desired data which you can use to populate your map. Then in your JSP you can render the map. Could you please push your code to github or something similar? It would be a great help to clarify your question.

Comment: Actually, the port is still added to the request, in the fromRequest method if you are in http by this code:
    if ((scheme.equals("http") && port != 80) || (scheme.equals("https") && port != 443)) {
   builder.port(port);
  }

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug from this method:

```
public static ServletUriComponentsBuilder fromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String scheme = request.getScheme();
    int port = request.getServerPort();
    String host = request.getServerName();

    String header = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Host");

    if (StringUtils.hasText(header)) {
        String[] hosts = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(header);
        String hostToUse = hosts[0];
        if (hostToUse.contains(":")) {
            String[] hostAndPort = StringUtils.split(hostToUse, ":");
            host  = hostAndPort[0];
            port = Integer.parseInt(hostAndPort[1]);
        }
        else {
            host = hostToUse;
        }
    }

    ServletUriComponentsBuilder builder = new ServletUriComponentsBuilder();
    builder.scheme(scheme);
    builder.host(host);
    if ((scheme.equals("http") && port != 80) || (scheme.equals("https") && port != 443)) {
        builder.port(port);
    }
    builder.pathFromRequest(request);
    builder.query(request.getQueryString());
    return builder;
}
```

If X-Forwarded-Host is filled, and there is no port it's because we are on the port 80. But the else

```
else {
    host = hostToUse;
}
```

So this case is a mixed case where the host is readed from the X-Forwarded-Host value but the port is read directly from the request (and it's the request the apache use to call tomcat).
We are working this issue here and did'nt find any alternative way to write a new UriComponentsBuilder (ok... maybe juste extends!)

Comment: Take a look at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder they did fix this issue in the method "getBuilder()"